# Supported Authentication Methods for Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, authentication

I would like to learn the official documentation for supported authentication methods for Active Directory for my implementation. I know these:

- Simple
- DIGEST-MD5
- GSSAPI

Could you refer me to the newest documentation for all the types of the authentication methods?

Comment: Are you need to know SharePoint Supported Authentication Methods for Active Directory ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I've integrated Sharepoint and Active Directory. I would like to connect programmatically get info from Sharepoint and Active Directory. I would like to know the different authentication methods to support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 supports a variety of authentication methods and authentication providers for the following authentication types:

- **Windows authentication**
  takes advantage of your existing Windows authentication provider (AD DS) and the authentication protocols that a Windows domain environment uses to validate the credentials of connecting clients. Windows authentication methods, which are used by both claims-based authentication and classic mode, include the following:

  - NTLM
  - Kerberos
  - Digest
  - Basic
- **Forms-based authentication**.
  is a claims-based identity management system that is based on ASP.NET membership and role provider authentication. Forms-based authentication can be used against credentials that are stored in an authentication provider, such as the following:

  - AD DS
  - A database such as a SQL Server database
  - An Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) data store such as Novell eDirectory, Novell Directory Services (NDS), or Sun ONE
- **SAML token-based authentication** uses the SAML 1.1 protocol and the WS-Federation Passive Requestor Profile (WS-F PRP). It requires coordination with administrators of a claims-based environment, whether it is your own internal environment or a partner environment. If you use Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS) 2.0, you have a SAML token-based authentication environment.

Read more at [Plan for user authentication methods in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've accepted it. Could you also check my other question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190774/mcpermissions-asmx-returns-404